# FB integration in iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook

I need to implement Facebook integration for my app. I added FBConnect sdk and all other codes in my project. But when am clicking on FB icon nothing happens. When i debugged the code...it goes everything correctly.But why its not getting loaded? Also i added my path in "User Header Paths" and added the app id in info.plist. What's the problem? Kindly help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/), it provides easier FaceBook integration and also a variety of other social services (Eg Twitter) which you can easily pick a combination of.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking help from **[here](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-fbconnect-facebook-connect-tutorial/)** and compare your steps.

Hope it will solve your problem!

Comment: ok..but still u are not able to get it! not getting loaded means?...u had checked ur connections and all

Comment: yes. I checked everything. But my facebook page is not getting loaded. Why so?